# how to add meta tags to AppMaker head

Tags: google-app-maker

I am trying to add a meta tag to the head of my deployed AppMaker application so it can display in fullscreen on the ios via the homescreen button.

I searched the settings but could not a way to achieve this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you want to insert a tag similiar

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

This is a hack and I am not sure if it will work but you can add an html widget and mark it as unsafe and put the above in there. This seems to work in Chrome, it respects those tags once it deciphers in body instead of the head.